# How to retrieve check-in date for users

Tags: php, mysql

hello I would like to be able to display the registration date for users after the date of 2022-01-25
But my query always shows me the same date

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM _users WHERE user_registered > "2022-01-25"';
$recipesStatement = $bdd->prepare($sqlQuery);
$recipesStatement->execute();
$recipes = $recipesStatement->fetchAll();

// On affiche chaque date une à une
foreach ($recipes as $recipe) {
?>
    <p><?php echo $recipe['user_registered']; ?></p>
    
<?php
}
```

Comment: var_dump($recipes); Is the data different?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Please provide sample data, expected result, and actual result.

Comment: everything is good the data comes out fine for all the columns except for the date which is always the same

Comment: That's no more than you said in the question. We cannot possibly diagnose anything without seeing the information I listed above. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. A data-related question is incomplete without any relevant data.

Comment: $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM _users  WHERE user_registered > "2022-01-25 00:00:00 "';

Comment: Again, that didn't provide any new information. Do you understand what I'm asking? And please [edit] your question when you have an update. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the help i edited my post with the solution that works

Comment: That's not how stackoverflow works. If you have a solution  please post an Answer, below. The question area is only for description of the problem. Please take the [tour] to learn about the site. Right now, to everyone else, including search engines, your question appears to have no answer

Answer (score 1):

```html
sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM _users WHERE user_registered > "2022-01-25 00:00:00"';
$recipesStatement = $bdd->prepare($sqlQuery);
$recipesStatement->execute();
$recipes = $recipesStatement->fetchAll();

// On affiche chaque date une à une
foreach ($recipes as $recipe) {
?>
    <p><?php echo $recipe['user_registered']; ?></p>
    
<?php
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).